# Synchronize my favorite sites with my Google account

Tags: google-account, synchronization, favorites

How do I to synchronize my favorites URLs, (all that I marked with the star) with my Google account?

I want to be able to to save my favorite sites in my Google account and not to lose the content if I would have a problem with my laptop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you using google chrome? if so you can use the browser sync and just use the book marks to save your "favorites"
[image]